# Как просмотреть все коммиты в git?

Tags: git, git-log

Потерялся коммит из неродительской ветки. Как сделать checkout?

`git log` его не видит

Comment: что значит "потерялся"?

Comment: @KoVadim выпал из лога.

Comment: значит кто то делал rebase. Но просто так один коммит выпасть не может (если кто то модифицирует древний коммит, то модифицируются и все его дочерние).

в git reflog коммит виден?

Comment: @KoVadim да, спасибо, виден.

Comment: @KoVadim а как сделать мой коммит главным. Потому что при git checkout master меня унесло далеко назад. И будущие коммиты перестали быть видны.

Comment: переключитесь в мастер (вы же там хотите сделать свой коммит "главным" - то есть самым последним?) и сделайте `git reset --hard <sha>`. но это плохо. Луче сделать `git checkout <sha>`, потом создать на базе этого ветку `git branch my_branch`. Теперь коммит не будет потерян.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

для просмотра всех коммитов во всех ветках (с псевдо-графическими элементами для отображения связей между коммитами) можно использовать команду:

```
$ git log --all --graph --decorate
```

пример вывода для репозитория [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) (вставляю картинкой, чтобы показать раскраску):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

если эти параметры надо использовать часто, можно сделать [псевдоним (alias)](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B#%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-Git). например, `la`:

```
$ git config --global alias.la 'log --all --graph --decorate'
```

тогда можно будет вызывать ту же команду короче:

```
$ git la
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503759/179765) на экран выводится слишком много дополнительной информации. Я бы рекомендовал добавить вот этот алиас в `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    tree        = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Или с помощью комманды:

```
$ git config --global alias 'log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit'
```

Пример вывода:

```
$ git tree
* ccfd449 Require to return undef if no digits found
*   93dd5ff Merge pull request #4 from KES777/clean_api
|\  
| * 39d82d1 Fix tests for debugging debugger internals
| * 67107f6 Set { dd } and { ddd } flags based on { debug }
| * bc2a378 Improve debug output: finish debug infomation early return
| * d71a97e Remove direct access to $DB::sub and pass its value as argument
| *   a435005 Merge branch 'redesign_interactions' into clean_api
| |\  
| | * a06cc29 Code comments
| | * d5d6266 Remove copy/paste code
| | * c0118fa Allow command to choose how continue interaction
```